# pandas use cumsum on a column and create a new boolean column that mark edge case as True

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have the following `df`,

```
year_month    pct
201903        50
201903        40
201903         5
201903         5
201904        90
201904         5
201904         5
```

I want to create a boolean column called `non-tail`, which satisfies the following condition,

```
df.sort_values(['pct'], ascending=False).groupby('year_month')['pct'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().le(80))
```

that in `non-tail`, any next value in `pct` that will be added which makes cumsum immediately great than 80 will be mark as `True` as well, so the result will look like

```
 year_month    pct    non-tail
 201903        50     True
 201903        40     True
 201903         5     False
 201903         5     False
 201904        90     True
 201904         5     False
 201904         5     False
```

Comment: Why 90 return True ?

Comment: Why the first line is `True`?

Comment: @WeNYoBen when `df` groupby `year_month`, in `201904`, the `cumsum` add `90` immediately great than 80

Comment: Follow up question , why 40 is True

Comment: @QuangHoang tried to use `Series.cumsum` on `pct` after `groupby` `year_month`, that if the cumulative sum of the values is less than 80, the row corresponding to it is flagged as `True`;

Comment: @daiyue if we use `Series.cumsum` the second row would be equal to 90 so it should be False

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I will do

```
df.pct.iloc[::-1].groupby(df['year_month']).cumsum()>20
Out[306]: 
6    False
5    False
4     True
3    False
2    False
1     True
0     True
Name: pct, dtype: bool
```

Comment: nice thinking out of the box!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC,  you need to shift the `cumsum`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['year_month','pct'], ascending=[True,False])
(df.groupby('year_month')['pct']
   .apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().le(80)
                     .shift(fill_value=True)
         )
)
```

gives you:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: pct, dtype: bool
```

Comment: @ScottBoston I think the logic works  since OP wants to mark `cumsum immediately great than 80` as `False`.